# TypeError: Illegal Invocation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics

We're running a Create React App (CRA) web app, to which we've added Google Analytics v4. We initiate analytics using the [ga-4-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ga-4-react) npm package. Manual initialization in `index.js`

```
const ga4react = new GA4React(process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID);

ga4react.initialize().then((ga4) => {
    ga4.pageview(window.location.path);
}, (err) => {
    Sentry.captureException(err);
});
```

We're receiving hundreds of errors from the `gtag/js` file to our Sentry error monitoring platform. This error doesn't really say much to us and we've spent two days trying to find out if anyone's run into a problem like this, but so far we've come up empty. It also doesn't seem to affect user experience, but it's rather annoying for us to monitor.

The error is reported as so to Sentry.

```
TypeError zq(gtag/js)
Illegal invocation

gtag/js in zq at line 477:453
{snip} ))}}},zq=function(a,b,c){var d=a+"?"+b;c?$c.sendBeacon&&$c.sendBeacon(d,c):pd(d)};var Eq=window,Fq=document,Gq=function(a){var b=Eq._gaUserP {snip}
```

We also receive as many errors from ga-4-react (the catch-block in the code snippet above). We also tried using the analytics snippet with [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet), but had the same result.

This error seems to be generated by a number of browsers (Chrome, Opera, Safari, mobile browsers) on many platforms (Android, Windows 10, OS X) so we can't really pinpoint any specific route, platform, browser that's common with these users.

I also tried to replicate this with AdBlock, blocking trackers, using Do Not Track, but nothing.

Comment: Atm we're trying to embed the script to static index.html file using environment variables to see if this solves our issue.

Comment: This did not work. We're still receiving TypeError from gtag/js

Comment: Well, we just ended excluding errors from external scripts since we have no control over this.

Comment: Interesting case. There’s a small chance that it’s indeed a bug in google’s script. I can only access a different version of gtag.js from my side, cannot find a `zq` function in [this version](https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js)

Comment: From the error message you post, we can already pinpoint to the `$c.sendBeacon` call. “Illegal invocation” happens when you call native API with a wrong context object. `$c` should be the builtin `navigator` interface, `navigator.sendBeacon` must be called together with `navigator` as its context object. Otherwise you got this error. If my theory is correct, you can reproduce with this line: `navigator.sendBeacon = navigator.sendBeacon.bind({})` run it before initialize GA.

Comment: So it could be some user side extension messing with you. But you mentioned that happens on mobile browser too, which is weird. AFAIK, “Illegal invocation” is chrome specific error message, have you got other messages (of the same error) from other platforms? If you don’t see other message, well, another possibility is the same extension is also tampering the user-agent field or the kind, so as to pretend to be other platform but in fact it’s just chrome.

Comment: @Rcls if _excluding errors from external scripts since we have no control over this._, then what is expected out the question? I mean if the external scripts are flagged by `sentry` are you expecting an answer to solve the external package?

Comment: We have these errors too. But we found the errors all originated from Azure ip's. So it seems some kind of crawler/link checker that is responsible in our case.

Answer (score 8):

Ran into the same issue on our site. This issue appears to stem from navigator.sendBeacon being called out of context, similar to the comment from hackape.

For context, this article has some pretty good info on sendBeacon and what it does, including a description of an error like the one you saw.

https://xgwang.me/posts/you-may-not-know-beacon/

In our case, we only saw Type Error: Illegal Invocation, but didn't see the other error message variants based on different browsers that they mentioned. In the end we ignored it in sentry for the moment.

Comment: I'm having the same issue in Sentry. Just wondering if you learned anything new since this post or if you still have the issue ignored in Sentry.

Comment: Sadly, no. We're ignoring it for now until we see enough instances of it to indicate that a large portion of users are being affected.

Comment: Im having trouble with Sentry not ignoring because it doesnt merge them well :/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code example

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import GA4React, { useGA4React } from "ga-4-react";

const ga4react = new GA4React("G-1JXXXXX");

function MyApp() {
  const ga = useGA4React();
  console.log(ga);

  return <div className="App">hi!</div>;
}

(async () => {
  await ga4react.initialize();

  ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <MyApp />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
})();
```

Comment: We're running React prior to hooks (16.13.1) so this is not really an option. I would also argue, that if you look at the source code (like I did) the hook simply initiates the same function as the manual initialization does. It simply does it inside a functional component and via a hook, which is helpful, but uses the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Use `react-ga` npm package for implementing Google Analytics with below code

Create helper file, which will help you for DRY concept

```
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';

/**
 * Initialize Google Analytics
 */
export const initializeGA = () => {
  ReactGA.initialize(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_KEY, {
    debug: true
  });
};

/**
 *  Push Page Tracking on Google Analytics
 */
export const pageView = () => {
  ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
};
```

Then initialize Google Analytics on your root component

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { initializeGA, pageView } from '../helpers/analytics';

export default function MyApp() {
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    initializeGA();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    pageView();
  }, [location.pathname]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Your root component text</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you are using old React versions it can be implemented using `class component` and lifecycle hooks `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate/componentWillRecieveProps` based on your react version. Sample for the same is.

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.unlisten = browserHistory.listen((location) => {
      console.log('route changes');
    });
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unlisten();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ga4.pageview(window.location.path);` but `path` is not a property of [window.location](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/history.html#the-location-interface)

Try using `pathname` instead:

```
ga4.pageview(window.location.pathname);
```

Answer (score -2):

Working for me. ***processData: false, contentType: false,*** is required for working.

```
var formData = new FormData($('#author_post')[0]);
 formData.append('t','author-add');
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'url-here',
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data:formData,
        success: function(response) {
           //success code
        }
 });
```